# AMPLPY decrypt and encrypt

Tags: python, ampl, amplpy

I am using amplpy to access AMPL from my python.
I want my dat file to not be in plain text.
Is it possible?
I cannot find any api to do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can import data from Excel or CSV files. Then fed into the data to the .mod file. Here, I am feeding a pandas dataframe to the .mod file. One thing to be remembered Pandas dataframe and amplpy dataframe is completely different.

`from amplpy import AMPL, DataFrame, Environment`

`df_mpij=DataFrame.fromPandas(df_mpij, index_names=('nodes','dertype'))`

`ampl.set_data(df_mpij)`